# Accessing Fragment objects from parent Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an ActionBarActivity that has a ViewPager with two Fragments and tabs created with ActionBar from the support library. My ActionBarActivity has also two buttons: cancel and save. When the save button is pressed, I need to get data from both of my Fragments. How do I do this? This data is stored fetched from the layout and stored in local variables in the Fragments.

Comment: you should be able get access to your fragments by use of `FragmentManager` by id or tag. `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()`

Comment: @AlexeyA. Hey, thanks for this. You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able get access to your fragments by use of `FragmentManager` by id or tag. `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` or `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()`